# Length of Longest Run Error in Java

Tags: java

I need to write a program that returns the longest run in an array.  The program runs fine until an empty parameter is given.  It produces a 0, but is instead showing an Out of Bounds Error.  How do I fix this?

Here is my current code:

```
public class Numbers{
 /**Computes the length of the longest run (sequence of 
  adjacent repeated values) in an array.
  @param values an array of integer values
  @return the length of the longest run in values
   */
public int lengthOfLongestRun(int[] values){
int lastVal = values[0];
int currentLength = 1;
int longestLength = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
{
    if (values[i] == lastVal)
{
    currentLength++;
}

else
    {currentLength = 1;}

   lastVal = values[i];

    if (currentLength > longestLength)
   { longestLength = currentLength; }
}
    return longestLength;

   }
}
```

Error: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: please share error stack trace

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: When I am using `int[] array = new int[]{1, 25,10, 34};`, I am not getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will produce an exception when the array is empty:

```
int lastVal = values[0];
```

You need to add a check to see if the array is non-empty before doing anything else:

```
public int lengthOfLongestRun(int[] values) {
    if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // The rest of your method goes here
    ...
}
```

In general, it's a good idea to state your method's assumptions about the content of its parameters in the form of parameter checks at the top of the method. For example, if you know that your method is not going to work when it is passed a `null` or an empty collection, add a check at the top to return immediately or to throw an exception, as appropriate.

**Note:** You should fix the `else` in your code to include both resetting the length and the last value, like this:

```
...
else {
    currentLength = 1;
    lastVal = values[i];
}
```

Comment: thank you! I tried to do something similar with an if statement values.length ==0, but it was later in code and without the second values== null which is, i assume, why it wasn't working originally!

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code:

```
int lastVal = values[0];
```

assumes there is at least one value in the array.

So add a defensive line:

```
        if (values.length==0){
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line:

```
lastVal = values[i];
```

i has a initial value of 1, and values is an empty array when an empty parameter is given.

Answer (score 0):

Get max sequence of a number in a array:

```
public int maxSequence(int[] A, int number) {

    int counter = 0, maxCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)

        if (A[i] == number)
            maxCounter = ++counter > maxCounter ? counter : maxCounter;
        else
            counter = 0;

    return maxCounter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to place a check for `empty` or `null` and take proper action for the same, before starting processing it.

In your case it's for `array`, refer the below code for the same:

```
  /**
     * Computes the length of the longest run (sequence of adjacent repeated
     * values) in an array.
     * 
     * @param values
     *            an array of integer values
     * @return the length of the longest run in values
     */
    public int lengthOfLongestRun(int[] values) {
        int longestLength = 1;
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            int lastVal = values[0];
            int currentLength = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                if (values[i] == lastVal) {
                    currentLength++;
                } else {
                    currentLength = 1;
                }
                lastVal = values[i];

                if (currentLength > longestLength) {
                    longestLength = currentLength;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // take some action either return some default value or throw some
            // exception
        }
        return longestLength;
    }
```